# White noise on my material after import to UE5 from Blender

Tags: rendering, blender, materials

Please have a look at the 2 screenshots attached. The first one is from Blender. The second one is UE 5.3.

1. My first question is why my model in Unreal looks brighter than in Blender?
2. Do you see kind of “white noise” on tongue and lips on the second screenshot from UE? What could be a root cause of that?

I would be really appreciated for your help

[image]
[image]

Comment: This brightening looks like a difference of lighting, or possibly gamma vs linear space colour. The noise looks like shadow acne. Searching those terms could give you some leads for things to try to confirm whether either is at play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions.

1. Regarding to the first one. My BaseColor had disabled sRGB, so I’ve enabled it. Additionally, I’ve changed strategy to export my textures from Substance Painter and import them in Unreal. The way is:

a. Template should be Unreal Engine 4 (PAcked). 8bits. png or jpg

b. Exported textures import to Unreal.

c. One of the maps contains Metallic, Roughness and AO. I enabled sRGB for this map in Unreal.

d. Then created node and connected R with AO, G with Roughness and B with Metallic.

e. Other textures are self-explanatory for connection.

It is as expected now.

2. Disabling r.Lumen.ScreenProbeGather.ShortRangeAO in Unreal Engine helped to get rid of that issue. Actually antialiasing TSR and MSAA helped too. I don’t know yet what is better for me. Will see

Thanks

Comment: It's a little unusual to use sRGB encoding for non-colour material parameters like roughness, metalness, or ambient occlusion. Is there a reason you chose this over storing these channels in linear space?

Comment: @DMGregory I cannot explain you reason from technical point of view. I didn't dig so deep. Just read some materials and watched video on youtube and then accumulated those information together. Then tested with my model and found best result.
For example, this video on youtube helped me understand about sRGB https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcpz9_stKgs